# How to prove this Dirichlet series identity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

On [this](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/pnt5.htm) website, within a proof of the prime number theorem, they boldly make the following claim:$$-\frac{\zeta'(x)}{\zeta(x)}=\sum_n \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^x}$$

Where $\Lambda(x)$ is the [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function).

Without anything to back it up. From some research, I can see that this identity is quite common and is related to Dirichlet Series, but I am yet to find a proof.

How can we prove this identity?

Comment: Take the logarithm of the Euler product (for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$ of course), and differentiate it.

Comment: I just saw in your profile that you're pretty young, a good way still to go until uni. So maybe the above doesn't yet mean anything to you. If so, don't hesitate to ask for clarification. If you understand what it means, try to follow the indicated route. If you have a problem somewhere, I'll happily assist.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you so much! People aren't usually willing to put in the time to clarify or explain, that's really nice. I know what the Euler product of the Riemann Zeta function is, but I'm not sure how taking the logarithm of it gets us from $\prod _{p}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}=\zeta (s)$ to $\log \zeta (s)=\sum _{{n=2}}^{\infty }{\frac  {\Lambda (n)}{\log(n)}}\,{\frac  {1}{n^{s}}}$

Comment: We get $$-\log \zeta(s) = \sum_p \log \bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr).$$ Differentiating gives $-\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ on the left, and on the right, we get to the first sum in Jack's answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perhaps this is a stupid question, but how did you go from the product of primes in the euler product to a sum of primes on the right of your equation?

Comment: That's due to the property $\exp(z+w) = \exp(z)\cdot \exp(w)$ of the exponential function. Due to continuity, we can extend it to convergent series, $$\exp\Biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^\infty z_k\Biggr) = \prod_{k = 0}^\infty \exp\bigl(z_k\bigr),$$ where the convergence of the product on the right follows from the convergence of the series. Then we see that one possible value (there are infinitely many possible values since $\exp$ has period $2\pi i$) of $\log \prod_{k=0}^\infty \exp(z_k)$ is $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty z_k$. Thus, informally, the logarithm of a product is the sum of logarithms of the factors.

Comment: Formally, one must be careful because the logarithm isn't globally defined, so the equality depends on the right choice of branches of the logarithm one uses. To get a convergent series, one must use the principal branch of the logarithm for all but finitely many of the factors, but one may take a different branch finitely often (and if some of the factors are negative real numbers, that is necessary, since the principal branch isn't defined for those).

Comment: But when one has an identity $\log f(s) = \sum \log f_k(s)$ and differentiates, the choice of branch of the logarithm becomes irrelevant, since such choices just add a constant term that vanishes upon differentiating.

Comment: @DanielFischer That makes so much sense, thank you so much. One more question: What do you mean by "branch" of the logarithm? I'm not that familiar with complex analysis, and while I've heard the term "branch cut" in integration, I've never been sure of what it means. Wikipedia isn't much help, either.

Comment: If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, a branch of the logarithm on $U$ is a continuous function $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\exp\bigl(f(z)\bigr) = z$ for all $z\in U$. A branch of the logarithm is automatically holomorphic, but _here_ that isn't important. The principal branch of the logarithm is the branch of the logarithm on $U = \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ that takes the value $0$ at $1$.

Comment: If $f$ is a branch of the logarithm on $U$, then so is $f_k \colon z \mapsto f(z) + 2k\pi i$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. If $U$ is connected, then all branches of the logarithm on $U$ (if any exist) differ by a constant multiple of $2\pi i$, but if $U$ has more than one component, the difference between two branches of the logarithm on $U$ can have different values on different components of $U$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow, that makes sense. This is so cool. This may be a stupid question, but why can't we define a "branch" of the logarithm over the entire complex plane, and not just an open subset of it?

Comment: First, $\exp$ never attains the value $0$, so a branch of the logarithm can exist only on subsets of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. For the next part, that one can't define a branch of the logarithm on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, consider how a branch of the logarithm would behave on the unit circle. If we have any function $f \colon \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\exp\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=z$ for all $z\neq 0$, such a function cannot be continuous. Consider $g \colon [0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $g(t) = f(e^{it})$. Then we have $g(t) = it + 2\pi i \cdot k(t)$, where

Comment: $k(t)\in \mathbb{Z}$. If $f$ were continuous, then $g$ would be continuous, and consequently also $k \colon t \mapsto \frac{g(t) - it}{2\pi i}$. A continuous integer-valued function on $[0,2\pi)$ must be constant, so we have $g(t) = it + 2k\pi i$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then $f(1) = g(0) = 2k\pi i$, and $\lim\limits_{t\to 2\pi} g(t) = 2(k+1)\pi i$. However, $\lim\limits_{t\to 2\pi} e^{it} = 1$, and thus we obtain the contradiction $f(1) = 2k\pi i = \lim\limits_{t\to 2\pi} g(t) = 2(k+1)\pi i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $s>1$ we have
$$ \zeta(s)=\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} \tag{1}$$
then
$$ \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{d}{ds}\log\zeta(s) = -\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{\log(p)}{p^{s}-1}=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\tag{2} $$
by just considering that $\frac{1}{p^s-1} = \frac{1}{p^{s}}+\frac{1}{p^{2s}}+\frac{1}{p^{3s}}+\ldots$ and rearranging.